# Application_Startup is called twice in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I am using VS2010 and **Silverlight 5**. The **Application_Startup()** is called **twice** each time I run the Silverlight project. Can anyone please help?

Thanks,
-Methil

Comment: Are you assigning the handler twice? Do a global search for the name of your Application_Startup handler, and set a breakpoint on the line that assigns it, and see how many times it gets called.

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with IIS - your Silverlight app runs in your local browser process, not in any IIS process. Are you using just one Silverlight project? Or do you have multiple Silverlight projects in your solution?

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I found the problem - Application_Startup was called twice - There was already a `Startup="Application_Startup"` in App.xaml and in the App Constructor(App.xaml.cs) there was another StartupEventHandler  `this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
The point was that i called WebContext in startup event. I don't know why it makes problem but it solved since i moved my code to mainpage loaded event.